# concatenate strings if isset them

Tags: php

i did a code, that has a sum of strings but the string can are set or not, but if i try concatenate an isset string, thats return to me a undefined variable, thats my code.

```
if ($sinal==="sim" || $parcelada==='sim' || $vista==='sim' || $automovel==='sim' || $_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim' || $entrada==="sim" || $fgts==="sim" || $financiado==="sim"){

    $p20 = ': O valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, caput) fica inalterável,
    independentemente de qualquer alteração que sofra o valor';
    if($sinal==='sim'){
        $p21 = ' do sinal (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($sinalValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    } 
    if($parcelada==='sim'){
        $p22 = ' da parcela (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($parceladaValorTexto , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($entrada==="sim"){
        $p23 = ' da entrada (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($entradaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($vista==='sim'){
        $p24 = ' do valor à vista (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($vistaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($fgts==="sim"){
        $p25 = ' do FGTS (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($fgtsValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($automovel==='sim'){
        $p26 = ' do valor do automóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($automovelValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim'){
        $p27 = ' do valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($imovelPagValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($financiado==="sim"){
        $p28 = ' do valor financiado (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($financiadoValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).')';
    }

    $paragrafo2 = $p20.$p21.$p22.$p23.$p24.$p25.$p26.$p27.$p28.';' ;  //here i need do anything to only concatenate if the strings are isset.

    array_push($paragrafos, $paragrafo2);
}
```

Comment: You can make use of `isset($_POST['x'])` in your conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting lots of different variables, append to the `$paragrafo2` variable in each `if` block.

```
if ($sinal==="sim" || $parcelada==='sim' || $vista==='sim' || $automovel==='sim' || $_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim' || $entrada==="sim" || $fgts==="sim" || $financiado==="sim"){
    $paragrafo2 = ': O valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, caput) fica inalterável,
    independentemente de qualquer alteração que sofra o valor';
    if($sinal==='sim'){
        $paragrafo2 .= ' do sinal (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($sinalValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($parcelada==='sim'){
        $paragrafo2 .= ' da parcela (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($parceladaValorTexto , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($entrada==="sim"){
        $paragrafo2 .= ' da entrada (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($entradaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($vista==='sim'){
        $paragrafo2 .= ' do valor à vista (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($vistaValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($fgts==="sim"){
        $paragrafo2 .= ' do FGTS (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($fgtsValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($automovel==='sim'){
        $paragrafo2 .= ' do valor do automóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($automovelValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($_POST['imovelPagamento']==='sim'){
        $paragrafo2 .= ' do valor do imóvel (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($imovelPagValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).'),';
    }
    if($financiado==="sim"){
        $paragrafo2 .= ' do valor financiado (cláusula 6ª, '.(array_search($financiadoValor , $topicosClausula6)+1).')';
    }

    array_push($paragrafos, $paragrafo2);
}
```